# How to make one .exe file which contain two .exe files and second will be automatically move to the Startup folder after Installation of First .exe

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have complete code of simple c# application there is some facility like daily Notes, Love Calculator and Birthday etc. but i want to implement birthday facility. i have a birth dates of persons which is stored in database. now my problem is that whenever person start the computer my application will pop-up and notify the persons Birthday details automatically.

i know i have to put my .exe in the Startup Menu but i can not put my whole application on startup menu because i want to show only Birthday details so please suggest me some ideas can i make More than one .exe in same C# application? one for User's Uses Purpose and second for Notify the User when He/She Start PC. 
If yes than one more question is it possible to Move my second .exe in Startup folder(C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup) Automatically?
Please help me to Improve this basic Application.

Comment: you can use command line arguments to solve your problem..pass a extra argument like "-BirthdayFacility" which you can check at start of application and invoke Birthday facility form only.

Comment: Try to understand my question dear

Comment: @HardikLakhani Try to understand Viru's comment. It's a nice and very common way of avoiding pointless multiple executables. Instead of putting a separate application in the startup directory, put a shortcut to your application in which you specify the command line arguments to use. Then check those command line arguments from your application.

Comment: Ok I will try to do something like this Thank you

Answer (score 2):

*I hope to have  understood the question.*

To achieve that, you do not necessarily need to split your program in two separate exe files. You should keep a single one that parses a startup option such as this example:

`birthday.exe -notify_mode`

In your main method check if `-notify_mode` is present in the `args` parameter, if so then you activate the notification, and show only birthday details, like the following pseudo-code:

```
IF args contains "-notifymode" then
  show_birthdays
  exit
ELSE
  show complete application
END
```

Then you can add your aplication to the startup list in the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

using the `-notify_mode` there.

All other links to your application (the user-excuted ones) will be without that argument.